# C#- Getting user input for Age.. but receiving error?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make improve my programming and getting things drilled into my head so I'm just quickly developing an application that gets user's input and prints their name. But also gets their input for "Age verification".

I'm practicing IF & ELSE statements as well as nesting classes.

However my compiler is shooting me an error and I just cannot seem to figure it out. I'm trying to get the user to input his age, and then proceed with the IF & ELSE statement.

> Compiler is shooting error that . ""Cannot implicitly convert type
>   string to int"

The only error in the program right now is the 
    myCharacter.age = Console.ReadLine();

```
using System;

namespace csharptut
{
    class CharPrintName
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Character myCharacter = new Character();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name to continue: ");
            myCharacter.name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}!", myCharacter.name);

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age for verification purposes: ");

            myCharacter.age = Console.ReadLine();

            if (myCharacter.age <= 17)
            {
Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry {0}, you're too young to enter!",myCharacter.name);
            }
            else if (myCharacter.age >= 18)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You can enter!");
            }

        }
    }
    class Character
    {
        public string name;
        public int age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well... The error message can't be any more explicit. What part are you not understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

character.age expects an Int but ReadLine() returns a string, you need to look at using `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse` to avoid exceptions

e.g.

```
  if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out myCharacter.age)) {
    Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a number!!!");
  } else if (myCharacter.age <= 17) { 
    Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry {0}, you're too young to enter!",myCharacter.name); 
  }  else { 
    Console.WriteLine("You can enter!"); 
  }
```

Comment: I have revised my code similiar to what you have mentioned. Could you possibly explain what the ! before int means?

I understand if I were to do if (int) != , that means Not equal. However, I've seen people use the ! expression before the variables, and have not found an answer for it in my book.

Comment: ! means not. You put it before a boolean to inverse the value.  So !true == false and !false == true

Answer (score 5):

As the error says you can't implicitly type a string to an int. You need to parse it into an int.

```
 string input = Console.ReadLine();
 int age;
 if (int.TryParse(input, out age)
 {
     // input is an int
     myCharacter.age = age;
 }
 else
 {
     // input is not an int
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to assign a string value to an int with this line:

```
myCharacter.age = Console.ReadLine();
```

Try:

```
myCharacter.age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: thank you so much!! Is that a must do, whenver trying to receive input that happens to be an integer?

Comment: You need TryParse, becuase an input of "a" will crash the program

Comment: @Bob Vale Yea a TryParse would be correct, but I believe this is just an exercise to learn not production code or anything.

Comment: @KyleRogers Yes but lesson one, never trust the user to enter something sensible!!! ;)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a student project.

The input coming from the ReadLine() is always of type string. You're then comparing a string to 17 which isn't valid, as 17 is an int. Use TryParse versus parse to avoid throwing an exception at runtime.

```
string typedAge = Console.ReadLine();
int Age = 0;
if (!int.TryParse(typedAge, out Age))
  Console.WriteLine("Invalid age");

if (Age <= 17)
  Console.WriteLine("You're awfully young.");
```

Comment: That should be `if (!int.TryParse(typedAge,out Age)) Console.WriteLine("Invalid Age");` TryParse sets the output to 0  and returns false on failure not -1

Answer (score 1):

OK. The problem here is that the age is defined as an int and Console.ReadLine() always returns a string so thus you have to convert the user input from string to integer in order to correctly store the age.
Something like this:

```
myCharacter.age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: An input of "a" will crash the program.... Never trust the users to type something sensible!!!

Comment: in that case you can use TryParse and validate the input.

Answer (score 1):

When you read input from the console, it returns it to you in the form of a string.  In C#, which is a statically typed language, you cannot simply take one type and apply it to another type.  You need to convert it somehow, there are several ways to do this.

The first way would be casting:

```
myCharacter.age = (int)Console.ReadLine();
```

This won't work because a string and an integer are two completely different types and you can't simply cast one to the other.  Do some reading on casting types for more information.

The second way would be to convert it, again there are a couple of ways to do this:

```
myCharacter.age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

This will work as long as you type in an actual number, in this case the Parse method reads the string and figures out what the appropriate integer is for you.  However, if you type in "ABC" instead, you will get an exception because the `Parse` method doesn't recognize that as an integer.  So the better way would be to:

```
string newAge = Console.ReadLine();
int theAge;
bool success = Int32.TryParse(newAge, out theAge);
if(!success)
   Console.WriteLine("Hey! That's not a number!");
else
   myCharacter.age = theAge;
```

In this case the `TryParse` method tries to parse it, and instead of throwing an exception it tells you it can't parse it (via the return value) and allows you to handle that directly (rather than thru try/catch).

That's a little verbose, but you said you're learning so I thought I'd give you some stuff to consider and read up on.

Comment: thanks for the explanations. Really helps. Much appreciated!

I believe what if(!success) means, just clicked in my head... Its simliar to !=  ..  so in other words. If NOT successful, it outputs the Console.WriteLine? I love when things just .. "clicK" .. THanks!